# How to SELECT the last user logged on to a computer given the Computer, User and LogonTime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

If I run this query to get a list of users logged on to each computer:

```
SELECT
    T0.Computer,
    T4.[User],
    T4.[Last Modified]
    FROM Table1 T0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 T4 ON T0.Guid = T4.Guid
    Where T4.[Last Modified] >= getdate()-30 -- Logged in the last 30 days
    ORDER BY T4.[Last Modified] DESC
```

I get:

```
Computer     User    Last Modified
--------     -----   --------------
Comp1        UserA   2013-07-14 16:31:59.000
Comp1        UserB   2013-06-03 13:43:32.000
Comp1        UserC   2013-04-28 15:58:22.000
Comp2        UserD   2013-04-28 11:10:21.000
Comp2        UserE   2013-04-19 15:01:33.000
Comp3        UserF   2013-04-18 08:01:03.000
```

I would like to show the MAX([Last Modified]) to show only the last user to log on to each computer:

```
Computer     User
--------     -----
Comp1        UserA
Comp2        UserD
Comp3        UserF
```

It would make sense to say SELECT DISTINCT Computer, User ORDER BY [Last Modified] DESC
But you can't use ORDER BY without specifying it in the SELECT.

And MAX([Last Modified]) would only work if the User wasn't in the SELECT.

---

Thanks @Lamak

Is it possible to Pivot the Results to show the last two users?  We could change the Row number to User1, User2, etc.:

```
RN = 'User' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T0.Name ORDER BY T4.[Last Modified] DESC) AS VarChar)
```

Then the results could show:

```
Computer    User1     User2
--------    -----     -----
Comp1       UserA     UserB
Comp2       UserD     UserE
Comp3       UserF     NULL or ''
```

Comment: Updated my answer with your new requirement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  T0.Computer,
            T4.[User],
            T4.[Last Modified],
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T0.Computer ORDER BY T4.[Last Modified] DESC)
    FROM Table1 T0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 T4 
        ON T0.Guid = T4.Guid
    WHERE T4.[Last Modified] >= GETDATE()-30 -- Logged in the last 30 days
)
SELECT Computer, [User], [Last Modified]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

**UPDATED**

Try this for your new requirement:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  T0.Computer,
            T4.[User],
            T4.[Last Modified],
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T0.Computer ORDER BY T4.[Last Modified] DESC)
    FROM Table1 T0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 T4 
        ON T0.Guid = T4.Guid
    WHERE T4.[Last Modified] >= GETDATE()-30 -- Logged in the last 30 days
)
SELECT  Computer, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN [User] END) User1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN [User] END) User2
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 2
GROUP BY Computer
```